# CSS - make element with position relative/absolute fully visibile without using height/min-height?

Tags: css, position

maybe somewhat of an odd question but I'm stuck nevertheless.

I have an element structure like this:

```
<div class="one">
  <div>
    <h3></h3>
    <div class="two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.one {position: relative; height: 50px; }
.two {position: absolute; height: 500px; }
```

Is there a CSS way to make sure **.two** is fully visible, when I cannot use min-height or height on any element?

Thanks for help!

**UPDATE**
Here is an example: [tab view](http://www.stokkers.mobi/demo/tab.html)

Comment: will it have text or something in it?  If there's nothing in it why does it need to be visible.

Comment: one is a tab header, two is the tab content, so yes, there will be content in it. But either way (content/no content), the element is hidden behind what's coming after it

Comment: can you post a full case situation where it's being hidden.  Maybe use www.jsfiddle.net to mock it up.  As @Silver89 suggested, maybe a clear would fix it.

Comment: I could help if your question was more clear. You say you cannot use min-hieght or height, yet you have height set on both divs. Are you simply trying to create a tabbed content section?

Comment: I have put up an example. Hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, since `.two` is absolutely positioned, there's no way to get the relatively-positioned `.one` to expand automatically to accommodate the size of its child. If all you need is for `.two` to be visible, though, you can apply an `overflow: visible;` style rule to `.one`, which will allow `.two` to expand beyond the bottom edge of its parent.

Comment: not working. I have put up an example to make clear what's wrong. Thx for help so far.

Comment: So, when you relatively position your content div, its width is constrained to 416 px. Why not put your content divs inside a different parent element that would allow them to span the entire width of the page when positioned relatively, instead of just one tab's width? You're already using JavaScript, you might as well get your money's worth.

Comment: Nice idea, but I need to keep the element structure as it is, because this is the default structure created by Jquery Mobile which I'm using to do this.

Comment: Hmm... Well, in that case, you could try setting the child divs to `position: relative` and then giving them a percentage-based width greater than that of their parents, corresponding to the number of horizontal tabs (e.g: if there are three tabs, the width would be 300% minus the extra padding you have on the left and right sides of the element). Of course, this would require JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Nopez not possible with pure CSS.

Because the element is absolute positioned to container has no idea as to how high it is.

You could use a Javascript solution though. Or just give the container a height.